# Calculating L moments of a standard normal

Tags: normal-distribution, l-moments

As part of my research, I am having trouble calculating the 2nd L moment $\lambda_2$ and the third and fourth moment ratios $\tau_3$ and $\tau_4$ of the standard normal distribution, where L moments are defined as they are in this paper [(Hosking 1990)](http://www.cee.mtu.edu/~vgriffis/CE%205620%20materials/CE5620%20Reading/Hosking-L-moments-1990.pdf), page 3.

Take $\lambda_2$ for example.

$\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2} [ EX_{2:2} - EX_{1:2}] \\
\implies \lambda_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xF(x)f(x) dx - EX + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x F(x) f(x) dx \\
= \ \cdots \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2/2} dx + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ erf(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}) e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ erf(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}) e^{-x^2/2} dx$

There must be an error in my calculation as this is supposed to be equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi}}$.

$\lambda_3 = \frac{1}{3}E(X_{3:3} - 2X_{2:3}+X_{1:3}) = \int_0^1 x(F) (6F^2 - 6F + 1) dF$
$\lambda_4 = \frac{1}{4}E(X_{4:4} - 3X_{3:4}+3X_{2:4} -X_{1:4}) = \int_0^1 x(F) (20F^3 - 30F^2 + 12F - 1) dF$
$\tau_3 = \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}$
$\tau_4 = \frac{\lambda_4}{\lambda_2}$

$\tau_3$'s formula is rather involved.

EDIT: I was able to figure it out. Instead of working through the integral as an ugly function of exponentials, x's and erf, work through it as a function of a power of F multiplied by the inverse erf term. The latter is analytically tractable. I am not sure the former is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the formula (2.4) in the paper you refer to, we get (with $f$ the gaussian pdf and $F$ the cdf)
$$\begin{aligned}
\lambda_2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x (2F(x) - 1) f(x) d x \\
          &= 2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x F(x) f(x) d x\\
\end{aligned}$$
Let $g(x) = x f(x) = {x \over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2\over 2}$. This is the derivative of $G(x) = -{1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2\over 2}$. We have $G(x) = -f(x)$. Integration by parts gives

$$\begin{aligned}
{1\over 2} \lambda_2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x) g(x) d x\\
&= \Bigl[ F(x) G(x) \Bigr]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) G(x) d x \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f^2(x) dx \\
&= {1\over 2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} d x \\
&= {1\over 2 \pi} \sqrt{\pi}
\end{aligned}$$
and $\lambda_2 = {1 \over \sqrt{\pi}}$.

**Edit** I tried to check if the same computation is tractable for higher $L$-moments. I had hard times but after a while I found the following, which this seems ok but a bit cumbersome. Everything boils down to computing 
$$ I_k = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x F^k(x) f(x) dx.$$ 
Integration by part seem to lead nowhere. A change of variable $y = -x$ leads to
$$ I_k = - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} y (1 -F(y))^k f(y) dy,$$
hence
$$ I_k = - \sum_{\ell=1}^k (-1)^{\ell} {k \choose \ell} I_\ell.$$
For $k=2, 3$, this leads to $I_2 = I_1$. For $k=4, 5$, this leads to two linear equations in $I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4$, allowing to compute $I_3$ and $I_4$ from $I_1$. This can be continued... I really can’t find anything simpler. I think this trick is well known – but not by me.

Comment: Sadly it took me a little more than 12 minutes to figure this out (I am getting old), so I didn’t see your final edit and answered anyway.

Comment: Thanks Elvis. This is a useful way of thinking about it nonetheless.

Comment: No problem, it’s always good to do that kind of things from time to time. But I am curious about your solution. The solution you sketch is basically working with a change of variable $w = F(x)$. For $\lambda_2$ this gives $\sum_0^1 F^{-1}(w) w dw$, and $I_k$ is $\sum_0^1 F^{-1}(w) w^k dw$. Any computation done with $w$ can be mimicked with $x$. Do you have a simpler solution?!

Comment: Well, it happens to be more analytically tractable for numerical integration.  For example in Wolfram Mathematica (Alpha) this would calculate $I_1$: Integrate[Sqrt[2]*InverseErf[-1 + 2*x]*(x^1),{x,0,1}].  As one goes to higher $I_k$, as you rightly show, this becomes more and more useful...

Comment: Oh, I thought you had an analytic solution, not a numeric one. I think your intuition is wrong. If you’re performing numerical integration with fixed step size, the behavior of $F^{-1}(w)$ near to the bounds (where it goes to the infinity) could lead to very bad results. As an exact solution is available, you should go for it, but if for some reason you really prefer to do numerical integration, integrating the form with $x F^k(x) f(x)$ between -10 and 10 seems a better option to me.

Comment: I understand your concern.  However there was a perfect match to the theoretical results for $\tau_3, \tau_4$ and $\tau_5$.  I will however also carry out the calculation for the exact solution.  That is the most honest way.

Comment: If $X_n = \max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_i$ where the $Y_i$ are independent standard normal random variables, then $P\{X\leq x\} = [F(x)]^n$ and so $X$ has density $n[F(x)]^{n-1}f(x)$. So it seems that your integral for $I_k$ is related to the integral for the expected value of $X_{k+1}$, and thus $$I_k = \frac{1}{k+1}E[X_{k+1}].$$  A discussion of asymptotic values of $E[X_n]$ is available [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89030/15941) on math.SE

Comment: I'm not sure the discussion of asymptotic values of $E[X_n]$ are as useful in this context because our n's are so small @DilipSarwate.  Perhaps more useful is [this link](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/22992-Expected-Value-of-Order-Statistics-from-Standard-Normal-Distribution) which derives $E[X_4]$ in closed form.  The math is quite beautiful.